# ORA-00917: Missing Comma SQL Oracle error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and have just altered a table and added a column named Date_Employed

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD Date_Employed date;
```

My problem is that whenever I try to insert a value into the Date_Employed column i get an error `ORA-00917: Missing comma` when I type in the code below

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Date_Employed) VALUES (26 September 2001);
```

I would like to know whether the method I am using to try to input data into the column is correct? and if it is not, what is the correct way to insert date data into the column?

Also, I would like to know, why I am getting the error I described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper date format for Oracle and enclose it in single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Date_Employed)
    VALUES (DATE '2001-09-26');
```

Comment: Addition: 
Knowing your actual date format (for DATE) and timestamp format (for TIMESTAMP) might also help:

`select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter in ('NLS_DATE_FORMAT', 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT')`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO 
Employees (Date_Employed) 
VALUES 
(TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

You are getting error because oracle is not able to understand the date format you have given.